How to show current position marker on Map in Android (Kotlin)?
I am trying to add a marker at my current location on the map, but for some reason, my current location is null even though I have my location turned on in my emulator. It seems to be an issue with the location permissions as well because when I turn my location off, the location permissions stay granted. I can't seem to figure out the problem though.
private const val FINE_PERMISSION_CODE = 1
private lateinit var myMap : GoogleMap
private lateinit var currentLocation : Location
private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient : FusedLocationProviderClient

class MapActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map)

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        getCurrentLocation()

    }

    private fun getCurrentLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION), FINE_PERMISSION_CODE)
            return
        }
        val task : Task<Location> = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
        task.addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
            if (location != null) {
                currentLocation = location
                val mapFragment =
                    supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment) as SupportMapFragment
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
            }
            else {
                Log.d("Location", "null location")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if(requestCode == FINE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if(grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Log.d("Location", "location granted")
                getCurrentLocation()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Location Permission is denied, please allow the permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap : GoogleMap) {
        myMap = googleMap

        var curLoc = LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude)
        Log.d("Location", currentLocation.latitude.toString() + currentLocation.longitude.toString())
        myMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(curLoc).title("My Location"))
        myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(curLoc))
        myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12f))
//        myMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
    }


I am trying to find a way to get my current location because it always ends up as null here for some reason.

So here's how you can get your current location. I am skipping the permission part as you can do that yourself.
private fun isLocationEnabled(): Boolean {
        val locationManager: LocationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
        )
    }

 private fun getLastLocation() {
        if (isLocationEnabled()) {
           fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                val location: Location? = task.result
                if (location != null) {
                    setMarker(location.latitude, location.longitude, "", "", "", 0.0)
                }
            }
        }


fun setMarker(
        lat: Double,
        long: Double,
    ) {
      map.getMapAsync {
      val newPos = lat.let { it1 -> long.let { it2 -> LatLng(it1, it2) } }
                it.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newPos, 17.5f))
                it.addMarker(
                    MarkerOptions()
                        .position(newPos)
                        .icon(
                            your_icon
                            )
                        )
                )
          }
   }

